# I am trying to Return the first node holding the value item or return NULL if none found

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list

I am trying Return the first node holding the value item or return NULL if none found. I have written 2 logic which according to me are the same. But Why I am getting wrong output in one of them.

```
//THIS IS GIVING ME THE CORRECT OUTPUT
struct nodeStruct* List_findNode(struct nodeStruct *head, int item){

    struct nodeStruct *temp_node=head;

    while (temp_node!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp_node->item == item)
        {
            return temp_node;     

        }
        temp_node=temp_node->next;  

    }
    return NULL;
}

//BUT ACCORDING ME THIS IS THE SAME LOGIC BUT IT'S GIVING WRONG OUTPUT.
struct nodeStruct* List_findNode(struct nodeStruct *head, int item){

    struct nodeStruct *temp_node=head;

    while (temp_node!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp_node->item != item)
        {

            temp_node=temp_node->next;


        }
        return temp_node;  

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: In the 2nd code you have unconditional `return` **inside** `while`

Comment: This `return temp_node;` statement you should keep in `else` block otherwise after first iteration itself it will return irrespective of whether item found or not.

Answer (score 2):

In the later case you need a continue or your function will return always

```
while (temp_node!=NULL)
{
    if (temp_node->item != item)
    {

        temp_node=temp_node->next;
        continue; // here
    }
    return temp_node;  
}
```

That said you could also use a for loop:

```
struct nodeStruct* List_findNode(struct nodeStruct *head, int item) {
    for (struct nodeStruct *temp_node = head;
         temp_node != NULL;
         temp_node = temp_node->next) {
        if (temp_node->item == item) {
            return temp_node;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when if condition is satisfied wouldn't the control goes back to the while loop again? And also isn't the return temp_node is automatically considered as else condition here?

Comment: I dont really understand your comment, but you are trying to invert the first if which is `if (this) then return; (else) next; (continue)` (the else being implicit). So the inverted test is `if (!this) then { next; continue; } else { return; }`